# Hot keys in XCode, line completion

Tags: iphone, xcode

So when typing in XCode, the autosense pops up with the method I might be calling.  If I hit tab and I start entering the values for the fields, on the last field, there is a ")" sign typically.  If I type ")" then I end up with an extra ")".  If I tab, I get whitespace.  When I end up doing is moving the arrow key past the ")" to put in my ";".  Is there a way around this?  I mean I'm typing away values, then I gotta hit the arrow to move past the ")".  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin that looks like it makes a few changes to Xcode auto completion features.  One is being able to type a ';' when stuck at the end of a line before the final bracket ']' and it will place the semi-colon in the correct place.  I haven't tried it yet.  Mostly because I didn't want to install the other features and also didn't know if it works with ')' as well.

http://nfarina.com/post/428544140/there-i-fixed-xcode-youre-welcome

Answer (score 0):

Command and right arrow should take you to end of line.

Comment: Right, that's what i've been doing.  Just didn't know if there was a better way.  Thanks though!